# How to get a Key Event in a Java Swing JFrame instance which has many JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, keylistener

I have a JFrame class which implements several JLabels  and JTextFields and I would like to perform an action when the focus is on that JFrame and the user press F1.

I have created the following class to handle the KeyListener:

```java
public class PropertiesKey implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    private Properties propertiesWindow;

    public PropertiesKey(Properties p) {
        propertiesWindow = p;
        System.out.println("DEBUG PropertiesKey");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

        System.out.println("DEBUG keyPressed");
        // F1 - Display Attribute Window
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F1){ 
            System.out.println("F1");
            if(propertiesWindow.isVisible()) {
                propertiesWindow.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                propertiesWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("KEY PRESSED " + event);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("KEY RELEASED " + event);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("KEY TYPED " + event);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ACTION PERFORMED " + event);
    }

}
```

Which I attach to the main JFrame class using:

```
this.addKeyListener(new PropertiesKey(this));
```

I am sure that this is actually attached as I see the System.out message when the Key listener class is created.

While this strategy works in another area of the program where I have an AWT Frame, I can not manage to get the KeyEvent propagated to my listener in this specific case of a JFrame populated with JTextFields.

I suspect that the TextFields -the focus on the JFrame will be always captured by one TextField- might be intercepting the event and not propagating it.

If that is the case, how can I fix it? Which strategy/pattern is used to capture Key events at JFrame level?

It it is not the case, how could I further troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyListener` only works (in most cases) for components that are currently focused. It also won't work if you add it to a container of the focused component in case when that component consumes key events. Registering a keyboard action would be a better way to approach window-wide hotkeys.

Here is a small example of how it could be done:

```
public class FrameHotkey
{
    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

                frame.setLayout ( new FlowLayout ( FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15 ) );
                frame.add ( new JLabel ( "Field 1:" ) );
                frame.add ( new JTextField ( "Field 1", 15 ) );
                frame.add ( new JLabel ( "Field 2:" ) );
                frame.add ( new JTextField ( "Field 2", 15 ) );

                // Hotkey for the F1 in window
                frame.getRootPane ().registerKeyboardAction ( new ActionListener ()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed ( final ActionEvent e )
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( frame, "F1 have been pressed!" );
                    }
                }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke ( KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0 ), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW );

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.pack ();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
                frame.setVisible ( true );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Note that I'm registering hotkey on `JRootPane` of the `JFrame` here, but it generally does't matter because condition is `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` - meaning that you can register it on any component in the window and as long as the window is focused in the system you will receive the action event.

Alternatively, if your application has a `JMenuBar` with menu items that would perform the actions you desire - you can specify accelerators for those menu items and they will handle the action upon specified hotkey on their own.

I also recommend reading the article from Swing tutorial **camickr** offered in the other answer.

Comment: The API for `registerKeyboardAction(...)` states: *This method is now obsolete, please use a combination of getActionMap() and getInputMap() for similar behavior.*

Comment: Both Mikle and camickr information has helped me a lot to understand how to implement this.

Comment: (1-) for promoting the usage of obsolete methods.

Comment: Haven't noticed it in the JavaDoc until now, I wonder why it was not marked as `@Deprecated` in that case. Either way it is simply an utility method for assigning a hotkey through InputMap and ActionMap instead of using them directly.

Comment: That method uses an ActionListener which was an older approach. The new Swing Key Binding API is designed to bind an `Action` to a `Keystroke`. That method wraps the ActionListener in an Action so the binding will work. The point is you should be using the Action API as it provides more functionality than a basic ActionListener. An application should be developed using current features. All Swing components use Actions for the Key Bindings.

Comment: While it is true that it uses an `ActionListener` instead of an `Action` - in many cases it is simply enough for the task and there are no real issues with it. Also my point here is - as long as it is not marked as `@Deprecated` - it remains a functioning public API in Swing. I just find having to read through JavaDoc comments of each public method or class in JDK on each new release to ensure that it is not obsolete/outdated/broken ridiculous.

Comment: Just a note - it's not a complaint to you, it's a general complaint to such questionable things in JDK in general. I do appreciate that you mentioned this one :)

Comment: The point is the answer is promoting the use of an ActionListener instead of an Action even though Swing is designed differently than AWT. Swing was designed to use an Action. As you say for something basic like this their is no difference so you should be promoting the newer features not older features. * I just find having to read...* - which is why I made the initial comment, to make you aware of this so you don't keep promoting this method. It is methods like this that would be candidates for deprecation in the future. So it is better to keep the code clean now.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a KeyListener. Key events can only be generated for the component that has focus. The frame will not have direct focus, only a component added to the frame.

Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. With key bindings you can map a `Keystroke` to an `Action` even when a component doesn't have focus. Make sure you use the appropriate `InputMap`.

In this case if you want to add a general handler for the frame you would add the key bindings to the "root pane" of the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Also read the section on [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for the benefits of using an `Action`.